# What should be White’s move here in which each side has just a king and a knight?

Tags: analysis, endgame, draw, knights

```
[FEN "8/8/8/2k2N2/2n1K3/8/8/8 w - - 0 1"]
```

Is this position a draw?

Answer (score 8):

Most people agree that this is a draw due to insufficient material, but FIDE and some chess websites say that a mate is possible.  Once you could also claim insufficient losing chances, but with increment clock, this rule has vanished.

To eliminate any possible mate, I would try to lose the knight.  The best move is Nd6 and chase the black knight until the draw is agreed upon.  An equally good move is Ne3 with the same objective.

Answer (score 3):

If you have used up your clock time in this position, you have lost the game since a mate is possible.

If you have some time left and with increment clocks it is easy to make 50 moves and claim a draw (the opponent will normally agree to a draw long before).

If you are not in increment mode and have less than 2 minutes left, you may claim a draw and every arbiter will agree to it.

Answer (score 3):

It's 99.99% a draw. The only reason why it's not 100% a draw is that if one side is just being lazy, they could be checkmated by the other side.

The mate would be the king in the corner, the knight right beside it, the other side's king 2 square in front of it, and the other side's knight on the only other square where it can check the enemy king.

FEN: 6nk/5N2/6K1/8/8/8/8/8 w - -

URL: https://lichess.org/editor/6nk/5N2/6K1/8/8/8/8/8_w_-_-

(did the position on lichess)